# HtmlUnit: waitForBackgroundJavascript() will not end?

Tags: javascript, redirect, htmlunit

I am working on a project that involves going to a webpage, entering a search term, and retrieving information about that search term. Entering a search term will cause a redirect, and thus I have called

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavascript();
```

The idea is that this will return 0 once all javascript redirects are complete. However, it seems to continuously be stuck on returning 6. Running a separate time has it stuck on 10. What reasons might cause this from not completing? I have waited for about 10 minutes so far, and the webpage loads almost instantaneously in a normal browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing a long value as a parameter to this function? I'm assuming you have but just in case, the long value passed to this method waits for that amount of time (in milis) before returning the number of javascript background jobs still in progress. So if you were to do:

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavascript(10000);
```

This means that after ten seconds you will get back the number of background jobs still in progress. If it's stuck at a certain return value, that means there are background processes that have been started that have not finished within the specified time.

Check to make sure you haven't got anything looping on a `setInterval()` function in the javascript code.

Also for reference: [The HTMLUnit Docs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#waitForBackgroundJavaScript%28long%29)